# Weird Char in String

Tags: javascript

I make a service call and I get this string `"lastName":"DÃ¼sedau"`

As you can see this is quite strange, but if you convert this to UTF-8, it is correct. https://encoder.mattiasgeniar.be/index.php

The problem is that in the UI it appears that weird chracters even tho I have charset utf-8

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
 <meta name="description" content="'moduleApp'" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

My Service:

```
promises.People.$promise.then(function(data) {
        this.people = data.People; // JSON that has lastname
    });
```

How can I remove this weird characters from the json?
I use AngularJS

Comment: The server is not sending UTF8

Comment: And if you control the source...fix it there.

Comment: @mplungjan let's assume it is impossible to change that. Can I fix on the UI?

Comment: Your server says it sends UTF-8 (_Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8_). Encode the file using UTF-8 when saving it.

Comment: @user11341081 sure, you can parse the string and decode UTF-8 multibytes into the proper character ... but seriously? Fix the Source. wether the encoding of the file is wrong or the Server doesn't include the charset in the `Content-Type` header, fix that! Don't mess around with broken data.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you absolutely cannot fix the server

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent(escape(`"lastName":"DÃ¼sedau"`)))
```

Alternatively have a proxy read the latin and re-encode it in UTF8 before sending it to your client

Answer (score -2):

`Ã¼` (as in `0xC3 0xBC`) is [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) for `ü`, aka [U+00FC 'LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00fc/index.htm). You obtain it when you encode it as UTF-8 and parse/render it as some single byte encoding such as [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), where `0xC3` stands for [U+00C3 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c3/index.htm) and `0xBC` stands for [U+00BC 'VULGAR FRACTION ONE QUARTER'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bc/index.htm). This suggests that data was originally stored as UTF-8 and was misinterpreted somewhere upstream.

The very first check you could make would be to open your browser's developer tools and inspect the server's response, taking into account that valid JSON can only be encoded as UTF-8. Move on from there.

Answer (score -2):

maybe you should try this

```html
<meta contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: does not work...